# c++ context free grammar library

Tags: c++, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

I need a c++ library that will allow me to parse a file. It's not in XML, or any other standard. It looks like I might be able to do it with regular expressions, but I'd prefer something where I give it a context-free grammar and it gives me a parse tree. It also has to be able to accept floating point values, and let me see what they are.

I would prefer something I can just download with the whole sudo apt-get thing instead of having to install it myself.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use C++11, you can use a header-only library called PEGTL that can be found at https://github.com/ColinH/PEGTL.  It's simple and it is header only so you can just download the library to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Boost.Spirit? Spirit.Qi looks like it might be useful to you:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Standard solution to this is still lex/yacc, with GNU implementation flex/bison. Usually used to generate C; but with appropriate parametrization C++ can be generated as well.